# 16:9 ratio video with other responsive components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, responsive-design

I am trying to build a HTML layout for the following wireframe -
[image]

Its basically two columns of content. First one is bootstrap `col-8` and the second is `col-4`.

Now inside the first column, I have a video component which needs to resize responsively based on available width (66%). For this I am using the following CSS code -

```
.video-embed {
  position: relative
  padding-bottom: 56.25%
  height: 0 
  overflow: hidden

  iframe {
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    left: 0
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
  }
}
```

below the video is a 300px high static content which has 100% width. I dont mind if this goes a bit below the viewport in some screens.

In the other column, I have a 4:3 container which again I am using code like above to maintain proportions without explicitly setting the height.

Below that there needs to be a section which needs to simply occupy available height & width in the page.

but since the element on top of that (`4:3`)  does not have a fixed height and even the video does not have a fixed height, I am not able to layout this last component (bottom right).

Am I going in the right direction with bootstrap? Is there any other layouting technique I can follow to layout all these things?

Most important piece of this layout is the 16:9 video. Im kinda new to UI design so finding it hard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what version Bootstrap, but since version 3.2 you can use built-in embedded classes (see responsive embeds @ https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp):

```
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>

<!-- 4:3 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

You can check out also frameworks like http://videojs.com/getting-started/#customize